# I have created a group in Openerp(locally).How to import it to my actual Server

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have created a Group in my local machine.Now i want to have same group in my actual server.I'm getting error when i try to export this Group from Local server and importing it on my actual server.Can any one help me? Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go To Settings -> Users -> Groups

Then Use List View(Tree View)

Select the group(s) you want to use then export it with compulsory (neccessary) fields

Use this export via module update or import it as csv

Comment: Thanks alot. Prevoisouly i was missing the neccessary field.So i couldn't do it properly.